# How to run Laravel Websockets in production (ubuntu + apache2)?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

I'm using the Laravel Websockets package https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction.

In my local dev server I run it using `php artisan websockets:server` and it works fine, but I would like to know how can I run it in my production server (Ubuntu + Apache2).

Comment: Is this a product support question better suited for a Laravel Websockets forum?

Answer (score 2):

After run your websocket server, you need proxypass to your apache. like below config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName your.domain.com
ProxyPass / http://localhost:6001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:6001/
</VirtualHost>
```

change 6001 to your websocket port.

To run in background you need to add your websocket server in backround using nohup or [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) . example:

```
pm2 start "php artisan websockets:server"
```

or using nohup

```
nohup php artisan websockets:server
```

Comment: My suggestion to have supervisord , so you can setup php artisan websockwt:serve

Comment: I still have to run `php artisan websockets:serve` on production? Or just the apache config is enough?

Comment: @Fantasmic you need to run it using supervisord, pm2 or nohup

Comment: Can anyone help how to run in Nginx Server?

Comment: How about running it in ssl?

Answer (score 0):

You can use supervisord , you can install and have configuration file to run command php artisan web socket:serve